# python regex for slicing string

Tags: python, regex

Is there any way to use regex for the following?

```
str_ = 'start_sampleString_data_2018-11-18'
new_str = str_[6:-16] // basically new_str -> "sampleString" and remove everything else
```

Is there any way to do this via regex?

The string is format will always be like... 
`'start_' + 'someSampleString' + '_data_' + 'someDateIn(yyyy-mm-dd)`
Only need to be able to extract 'someSampleString' from it.

Thanks!

Comment: the requirement is to use regex as a better way instead of using magic numbers that's why

Comment: avoid regex, just split the string on `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this simple regex should do:

```
import re

string = 'start_sampleString_data_2018-11-18'

re.findall('start_(.*)_data', string)
```

output:

```
['sampleString']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.search`

**Ex:**

```
import re

str = 'start_sampleString_data_2018-11-18'
m = re.search(r"start_(\w+)_data", str)  #Or m = re.search(r"start_([a-zA-Z]+)_data", str)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
sampleString
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of lookbehind and lookahead:

```
import re

str = 'start_sampleString_data_2018-11-18'
print(re.search(r'(?<=start_)(.*)(?=_data)', str).group())

# sampleString
```